# What does it mean by $x \not\in A \smallsetminus B$ when $B \subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B \subset A$. Then by set definition $x \not \in A \smallsetminus B$ implies $x  \not \in A$ and $x \in B$. But to me this is absurd. What is happening when $x  \not \in A \smallsetminus B$ when $B \subset A$? Thanks.

Comment: Your implication is wrong.

Comment: NO. $x \notin A \setminus B$ is $x \notin A \text { or } x \in B$.

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x \in A \setminus B$ means $x \in A$ *and* $x \not\in B$. So $x \not\in A 
\setminus B$ is the negation of that: $x \not \in A$ *or* $x \in B$.